# Is it possible to change the size of the text in an HTML input tag?

Tags: html, input

I have a client who wants bigger text in an `<input>` box.  I would prefer to not have to make custom graphic button for this as it's on a really resource-constrained embedded system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` tag can be styled just like any other element in HTML, including padding, borders, text font face/size, etc.

```
input{
    font: sans-serif italic 20pt bold;
    border: 2px black solid;
}
```

Or what ever you would like.

Comment: Thanks guys, seems obvious now :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify the `font-size` you want for the element:

```
input {
    font-family: tahoma, verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

I have used a relative size (`em`), so the ratio will keep if a user has a larger font size defined in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

not only should you increase the `font-size`, you may also have to increase the `height` and `line-height` properties if the input element doesn't scale with the text (depending on how your styles were set).  Also, be sure to check across all browsers, as forms can be very finicky.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it is possible and also simple to do!

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="example_input" name="example_input" />
```

And the CSS:

```
.example_input{
font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif 20px bold;
border: 1px black solid; //optional
}
```

Hope it helped!

EDIT: Example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hart1994/t2ybZ/)